# How can I convert any numbers, for example 822042461 (string-type) to 822042461 (double-type)?

Tags: string, visual-c++, type-conversion, double, c++17

How can I convert any numbers, for example 822042461 (string-type) to 822042461 (double-type) in C++ ?? Thanks a real lot !

Comment: That may depend on what programming language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sscanf may be useful:

```
/* sscanf example */
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char sentence []="822042461";
  double i;

  sscanf (sentence,"%lf",&i);
  printf ("%lf\n",i);

  return 0;
}

$ gcc -o /tmp/test.exe  /tmp/test.cpp
$ /tmp/test.exe                      
822042461.000000
```